# Collapsing toolbar effect in compose using Motion Layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-motionlayout

I would like to make a collapsing toolbar effect in compose layout with a lazy column scroll.

Here is my effort

1. Create collapse_toolbar.json5 file in the raw folder.
2. Define motion layout in compose function and define all widgets.

I have added Text, Icons and Image to the Box layout. when I scroll up I want collapsing toolbar effect in the motion layout.  but I can only see the box layout.

**Expanded collapsing toolbar**

[image: Expanded collapsing toolbar]

**Collapse Toolbar**

[image: Collaps Toolbar]

**collapse_toolbar.json5**

```
    {
  ConstraintSets: {
    start: {
      box: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 230,
        start: ['parent', 'start'],
        end: ['parent', 'end'],
        top: ['parent', 'top']
      },
      help_image:{
        width: 80,
        height: 120,
        end: ['box', 'end', 16],
        top: ['box', 'top', 16],
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom',8]
      },
      close_button:{
        start: ['parent', 'start',8],
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom',8]
      },
      title: {
        width: 36,
        height: 36,
        start: ['close_button', 'end', 16],
        bottom: ['close_button', 'bottom'],
        top: ['close_button', 'top']
      }

    },
    end: {
      help_image:{
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom'],
        end: ['box', 'end']
      },
      box: {
        width: 'spread',
        height: 56,
        start: ['parent', 'start'],
        end: ['parent', 'end'],
        top: ['parent', 'top'],
      },
      close_button:{
        start: ['box', 'start', 16],
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom', 16],
        top: ['box', 'top', 16]
      },
      title: {
        width: 36,
        height: 36,
        start: ['box', 'start'],
        bottom: ['box', 'bottom'],
        top: ['box', 'top']
      }

    }
  },
  Transitions: {
    default: {
      from: 'start',
      to: 'end',
      pathMotionArc: 'startVertical',
      // key here must be Key with capital K
      KeyFrames: {
        KeyAttributes: [
          {
            target: ['box'],
            frames: [0, 20, 50, 80, 100]
//            rotationZ: [0,  360]
          },
          {
            target: ['close_button'],
            frames: [0, 20, 60, 80, 100],
            translationY: [20, 40, 65, 85, 100]
//            alpha: [1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 1]
          },
          {
            target: ['title'],
            frames: [0, 100],
            translationY: [20,100]
//            alpha: [1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 1]
          },
          {
            target: ['help_image'],
            frames: [0, 30, 50, 80, 100],
            scaleX: [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0],
            scaleY: [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0],
            alpha: [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**setContent entry point**

```
setContent {
        val lazyScrollState = rememberLazyListState()
        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            topBar = {
                CollapsingToolbar(lazyScrollState)
            },
        ) { paddingValues ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(color = Color.White)
                        .animateContentSize(),
                    state = lazyScrollState
                ) {
                    // Add 5 items
                    items(100) { index ->
                        Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(36.dp), text = "Item: $index")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**CollapsingToolbar**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class)
@Composable
fun CollapsingToolbar(lazyScrollState: LazyListState) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.collapse_toolbar).readBytes().decodeToString()
    }

    val progress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex in 0..1) 0f else 1f,
        tween(500)
    )
    val motionHeight by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex in 0..1) 230.dp else 56.dp,
        tween(500)
    )

    MotionLayout(
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
        progress = progress,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .height(motionHeight)
    ) {

//        val boxProperties = motionProperties(id = "box")

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("box")
                .background(Color(0xFF4CC48E))
        )

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("help_image"),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.help),
            contentDescription = ""
        )

        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("close_button"),
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close,
            contentDescription = "",
            tint = Color.White
        )

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.layoutId("title"),
            text = "Help",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 16.sp
        )

    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with `MotionLayout`, but usually in compose you should use https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#nested-scrolling to get this effect

Comment: Thank you @PhilDukhov for your response. I have figured out the solution. It is not perfect but it is working fine. Here is my public repo https://github.com/arpit999/ComposeDemo/tree/collapsing_toolbar